# Fix MacOS Mount Point

Tags: macos, partitioning, mount, osx-el-capitan, disk-utility

I accidentally ended up renaming my non-OS partition originally named `Sanu` and mounted on `/Volumes/Sanu`. I then tried to rename it using `get info` but it didn't work. So I fired up terminal, did `cd /Volumes` and then `ls` was showing me `Sanu` as well as `Sanu 1`. I went into sudo mode, `rm -rf Sanu` and then `mv "Sanu 1" Sanu`.

So far all good.

2 problems:
 1. I'm not able to access my files from finder within /Volumes/Sanu. Able to cd into folders but when I double-click on a file, it says `file can't be found`. However, I can access the same from terminal using `cat or more`.
 2. Disk Utility reports that the Volume Sanu is mounted on
    `/Volumes/Sanu 1`

[Disk Utility image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sl8F.png)

[diskUtil list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otkbK.png)

```
$ diskUtil verifyVolume /Volumes/Sanu
Started file system verification on disk0s4 Sanu
Verifying file system
Using live mode
File system check exit code is 8
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error
```

Should I try to unmount and remount? I haven't tried unmounting. Nor have i tried re-booting my mac.

Please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFvNI.png) of `steps.txt`. From the finder, I cannot open but you can see that I just edited and saved the file using textmate. Also, the disk free space at the bottom in finder is reported correctly.

Will appreciate some pointers on how I can fix it.  My guess is changing mount path to `/Volumes/Sanu` should fix this

OS: Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 . Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Unmount and remount it. I don't know of a safer way to change the mount point of a mounted volume.

For future reference: my recommendation if this happens again is to unmount the volume, then remove the conflicting directory (check to make sure there's nothing important in it before deleting!), then remount the volume.

Comment: Sure. Let me try that. I'll take a backup before doing that. In my case, I already removed the conflicting directory but didn't unmount before doing that. That explains why all the files are accessible in terminal but but not in finder.